# Where to handle getting new access token with refresh token using Refit and Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, refit

I am currently using Refit and have been handling my auth stuff in an `AuthenticationService` where I set my Refit settings to have `AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter` use my `AuthenticationService.GetAuthenticationToken()` to get my `access_token`. The logic inside my `GetAuthenticationToken()` method checks the token expiration and will attempt to use the `refresh_token` to get a new `access_token` if it is expired. If all fails it will show the login screen of my app.

My test group has reported that they are asked to login frequently so I feel like there is something not working optimally in my design.

**Am I doing too much in the `AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter`?**

**Should I be doing this in a `DelegatingHandler` where I can resubmit the api request after getting a new `access_token`?**

I have background fetch stuff that happens in my app so I need to be able to have the `refresh_token` automatically get a new `access_token` during the background process.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I stumbled upon my issue. The sequence that created this problem in the wild is:

- app is backgrounded after user is logged in and using app normally
- the `access_token` expires while in the background
- background fetch runs getting a new `access_token` and `refresh_token` and doing normal work
- user foregrounds the app

The problem was that the new token info was not persisted when the background fetch ran. So, when the user foregrounded the app my `ResumeManager` checked `IsUserLoggedIn` which used the old token info, so it would see an expired `access_token` and tried to use an already consumed `refresh_token` since it was used in the background fetch. This resulted in an `invalid_grant` and the login screen was displayed.

The good news is, easy fix and my logic is fine, also it appears doing all this in the `AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter` is not a problem.

Hopefully this info helps someone else even though it was more a careless mistake than anything else.